# Extracting a file to the Executing folder after deployment in C#

Tags: c#, deployment

Okay, 
So I want to run a media file resource from my c# deployment such that it gets extracted from the project resources and then gets played via windows media player.

This works well while debugging

```
    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string mp4path = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), "Timi.mp4");



        File.WriteAllBytes(mp4path,LearnMedia.Properties.Resources.UNILAD);

    MessageBox.Show(mp4path);


   ProcessStartInfo ps = new ProcessStartInfo("wmplayer.exe", "\""+mp4path+"\"");
    Process.Start(ps);
```

And the messagebox shows where it extracts to, but when i deployed the project, the File does not get extracted to the program files even though the message box shows the path it needs to extract to;thereby the windows media does not see the file to be played.

Please help me out Gurus!

Answer (score 0):

Your application most likely doesn't have write access to Program Files as this generally defaults to Admins and Trusted Installer. It is more appropriate to create a directory for your application in ProgramData and use this for runtime resources.

Comment: is there anyway i could give acess to the application to write to Program Files or better still how do i create a directory in programdata?